# Having trouble getting my dropdownlist to display in my view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am basically trying to display a dropdownlist on my data entry view, and the dropdownlist keeps giving me the error "An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation". I have added "@Model MyModel" to the top of my view, but still can't get past this error. Does anyone have an idea of how to resolve this issue? I have a controller that looks like this

```
using MvcApplication1.Models;


namespace MvcApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class MyController : Controller
    {

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult EnterInfo()
        {
            GetUT myGetUT = new GetUT();
            ViewBag.uts = GetOptions();
            return View(myGetUT);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult EnterInfo(GetUT myGetUT)
        {
            ViewBag.uts = GetOptions();
            return View(myGetUT);
        }

        private List<UT> GetOptions()
        {
            List<UT> uts = new List<UT>();
            uts.Add(new UT() { ID = 1, Name = "1st" });
            uts.Add(new UT() { ID = 2, Name = "2nd" });
            uts.Add(new UT() { ID = 3, Name = "3rd" });
            uts.Add(new UT() { ID = 4, Name = "4th" });

            return uts;
        }

    }
}
```

and a view that looks like

```
@Model MyModel

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>EnterInfo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>

        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.UTID, new SelectList(ViewBag.uts, "ID", "Name", Model.UTID))
        Enter an Amount :-<input type="text" name="Amount" /><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit Info" />

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, ViewBag is a dynamic type, so I assume that is what it is complaining about. Try putting `public List<UT> UTs { get; set; }` as a property on `MyModel` and change your helper to use the UTs property from your model. Like this:

Controller:

```
public ActionResult EnterInfo()
{
    GetUT myGetUT = new GetUT();
    myGetUT.UTs = GetOptions();
    return View(myGetUT);
}
```

View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.UTID, 
    new SelectList(Model.UTs, "ID", "Name", Model.UTID))`
```

Edit: If it isn't obvious, your view should be typed to a GetUT type (because that's what you are passing in to the View() function in the EnterInfo action) - I assume that's what you mean when you said `@Model MyModel`. If not, change it to `@Model GetUT` and put the property on the `GetUT` class.